# I want to use Pexpect-pxssh to re-logging to remote host after reboot. Reboot device takes about 15 mins to get back online

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, pycharm, pexpect

Within the same script I want to be able to login to remote device via ssh, run some commands, reload device, and attempt to re-login after 15 mins once the device is back online.

```
commands = ['wr \n',
            'reload \n',
            '\r\n',]
username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
# Define a For loop Starts the loop for devices
for device in devices.keys():
    device_prompt = devices[device]['prompt']
    child = pxssh.pxssh()
    child.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer
    child.login(devices[device]['ip'], username.strip(), password.strip(), auto_prompt_reset=False)
    for command in commands:
        child.send(command)
        child.prompt()
   child.logout()
   child.close()
```

Comment: What _is_ the problem?

Comment: So this code only reloads the device and drops the ssh session. I need add a line that will automatically log back in or start a new ssh session after the device is back online. Device usually takes 15 mins to reload.